# Renaming the [danganeonpa] tags

Tags: discussion, status-completed, tags, tag-rename-request

I would like to propose renaming the tags for the Danganronpa series to use their full titles.

- [danganronpa](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/danganronpa) → [danganronpa-trigger-happy-havoc](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/danganronpa-trigger-happy-havoc)
- [danganronpa-2-goodbye-despair](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/danganronpa-2-goodbye-despair) (No change needed)
- [danganronpa-v3](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/danganronpa-v3) → [danganronpa-v3-killing-harmony](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/danganronpa-v3-killing-harmony)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

- Renamed [danganronpa](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/danganronpa) to [danganronpa-trigger-happy-havoc](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/danganronpa-trigger-happy-havoc)
- Renamed [danganronpa-v3](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/danganronpa-v3) to [danganronpa-v3-killing-harmony](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/danganronpa-v3-killing-harmony)

  - [danganronpa-v3](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/danganronpa-v3) is now a synonym